# Best way to automatically sort an unordered todo list?

Tags: python, list, sorting, unordered

My end goal is to have a script to process an unordered task list based on urgency (days till due) and importance (1-10). This mean just one box to input tasks, like so:

(3) Pay phone bill [due:3d]

This means no manual sorting, or placing each task in the correct order. The most I would ever do as far as changing things is changing the due date, or the importance of a task already on the list.

Comment: I'm flagging this question as 'too broad'. We know nothing about the meaning of the scores and there is unlimited amount of possible solutions to this.

Comment: @TonyBabarino I have edited to include sources.

Comment: People flagging this as too broad, may comment why they think it is.

Answer (score 1):

You need to come up with the right weight coefficients for each source.

```
score = x * importance + y * urgency + z * location
```

The algorithms you know about, are about how to determine the optimal coefficients, based on real classified data. That's called [Supervised Learning.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supervised_learning)

---

Assuming you have a table of training samples with:

```
[importance, urgency, location, score ] = [i,u,l,s]
```

The score assigned doesn't matter itself, but the relative score values should be representative of the the decision you'd take. A linear fitting for your solution would be:

```
a = [i, u, l] , a row vector of sources.

A= [a1  ; = [i1, u1, l1;
    a2  ;    i2, u2, l2;
    ... ;    ...;
    an  ]    in, un, ln]
```

a matrix of all your sources samples, one per row.

```
S= [s1;
    s2;
    ...
    sn]
```

a column vector with your score samples.

Then you can can calculate

```
B=(A*A')^-1 A'* S
```

B being an array [x,y,z] with your optimal weights.

- `A'` is the transpose matrix
- `(A*A')^-1` is the inverse of a square matrix
- `*` represent the matrix product in this context.

Use a math software or a math library for your vectorial operations.
MATLAB/gnuOctave being my recommendations. numpy an uglier alternative that'll also work.

---

If you are interested in why this works, it's a [linear predictor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_predictor_function), the optimal solution when you don't know any extra information about your samples.

Comment: So as a complete noob, is there a way I can do this pain-free? Unfortunately, this is wayyy out of my league.

Comment: This looks like a priority  issue, just get an array of samples, assign them a score and source for each case. Those are your training samples. Then do a linear fitting to find your optimal coefficients. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_predictor_function

Comment: Can you please give me an example of all of this in code? I hate to ask for handouts, but this is the big problem standing between me and my program ha. And the only thing I can't do myself *without* a handout.

Comment: xvan, this seems like a great answer to another question. It looks like the OP wants to merge three scores into one, so your first paragraph is fine - I can't see how the OP would need matrix maths and learning algorithms though.

Comment: How do you come up with the right merging weights? Machine Learning is all about how to select the optimal coefficients. My answer is mathematically optimal provided that you don't know anything else about the problem, and you want a linear merging.